# How to properly calculate amps from home consumption metering system like Shelly EM?

Tags: current, ac, current-measurement, home-automation

I am creating a system for detailed measuring of power consumption in my home. For that I am using Shelly EM, which is using 50A hall sensor clamped over my main line (single phase 240V AC) inside my circuit breaker box. Then I am gathering data from Shelly EM using ESP MCU that uploads them to my server.

Shelly only provides following data:

- Voltage
- Watts
- Power factor

Out of curiosity I created a graph for current as well, despite shelly is not providing it in its JSON output. I used following calculation (power is watts, pf is power factor, shelly report it negative most of time, no idea why):

```
current = power / (voltage * abs(pf))
```

My problem is that the reading I am getting are sometimes not making much sense, for example here it was reading 18A, but my circuit breakers are 16A

[image: current graph]

I suppose the problem might be that

- My calculation is wrong (I tried also removing power factor from it entirely, the graph was showing lower current overall, especially when consumption was low, but peaks were exactly the same, in this case again 18.4A)
- Shelly is reporting wrong values (maybe that hall sensor isn't so accurate? they report 1% accuracy though)
- Circuit breakers have some tolerancy to allow higher current than rated for? Unlikely IMHO
- Something else is wrong that I don't understand

EDIT: seems that circuit breakers allow more than 16A for limited amount of time, which might explain this

Graph zoomed:
[image: current meter]

Comment: It would help immensely if you could state what physical loads were connected and running when you made measurements. Your calculation method is correct. Try calibrating your measurements with a known load.

Comment: Sure, the load was electric water kettle and a washing machine + many small home electronics (wi-fi router, switch, etc. but they have less than 10W most of the load was the big stuff).

Comment: "Circuit breakers have some tolerancy to allow higher current than rated for? Unlikely IMHO" They can usually take like 2x their rated current for several seconds. So it's not unlikely at all.

Comment: I actually started the kettle just for experiment, I saw in graph that when my washing machine is running it's about 10A and I remembered that when the kettle ran it was also close to 10A, but also that I definitely ran both in the past and it never triggered the circuit breaker, so I wanted to understand what's going on, started both to see and to my surprise it indeed exceeded the circuit breaker rating (at least according to this calculation).

Comment: @Klas-Kenny ok that is definitely a new information to me, I always though that being safety device they must not tolerate anything above, if that's the case it may very well be that it really is drawing over 18A for couple minutes.

Comment: Indeed. A 16A breaker will usually take 18A for quite a while before tripping. They are not anywhere close to as ideal as one might expect.

Comment: The tripping curves of circuit breakers are normally specified by a letter (B, C, D being very common); specifically designed to trip at different currents applied for different amounts of time. The rated current is the "indefinite non-trip current at 20 °C", and a breaker will normaly have an "instantaneous trip current" at least three times higher.  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker#Standard_current_ratings) or [this](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2021/07/tripping-curves-circuit-breaker.html) for an explanation.

Comment: oh, so it means (I have type B) that I can run appliances up to 48A with 16A circuit breaker without it tripping? Wow I had no idea about this.

Comment: @petr ... yes, but not for very long!  You'll see the curves show it tripping after approx 10 seconds at 3x rated current.

Comment: The curve ratings are specifically designed to **not trip on inrush currents** of various sizes, you choose the curve depending on the type of load.  It's also temperature dependent: lower temperature has higher trip current.

Comment: Can you zoom in on the current graph?  What's the sampling rate, how long was the system "over" its 16A limit?

Comment: it collects data from shelly every 30 seconds, it was about 2 minutes at around 18A, the kettle boils water really fast, that's why it uses so much power :)